# Matching email ids to people names

Tags: pattern-matching, matching, string-matching

I have a database(say 5000 records) full of people names(first and last name). I also have a huge set of email ids (say around 30000). Now I have to match these email ids to people names where ever possible and discard other ids. So what I am currently doing is, I have made some patterns like:

`1. firstname.lastname@something.com
    2. lastname.firstname@something.com
    3. firstname_lastname@something.com
    4. lastname_firstname@something.com
    etc`

I also trying to use fuzzy search in both first and last names following above patterns.
But people tend to use lot of patterns in email ids. As of now I tend to get more than 1 result for some people. Is there a better way to do this to increase the probability in matching the emails correctly. I was searching a lot and didn't find any solid ideas.

Answer (score 0):

To make it a bit smarter you could assume any non alpha numeric is a name separator and use a regular expression, e.g.

$jan[^A-Z0-9]smith@.*^

But this doesn't help with your multiple matches. I think it's inevitable that you'll get false positives as your email format is not constrained. Given the size of your database i think you're stuck with doing some of this by hand :(